# GAS(jQuery使用)のスクレイピングで、class,idの振られていない複数のtableタグから、要素を取得したいです。

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

こちらのコロナ情報から、それぞれの市（横浜市、山北町等）のコロナ感染者の累計を取得（スクレイピング）したいです。
https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/docs/ga4/covid19/occurrence.html

【環境】
GoogleAppsScript
【利用ライブラリ】
Cheerio

GASでCheerioライブラリを使い、jQueryでの要素指定をして、データを取得するスクレイピングをしたいです。
サイトのtableタグ等に、class名、id等が振られていないため、要素数の番号で指定する方法で取得しております。

現状のコードは以下のとおりです。

```
  //スクレイピングスタートするURL
  const url = "https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/docs/ga4/covid19/occurrence.html";
 
  // UrlFetchAppにて取得（UTF-8を指定）
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText('UTF-8');

  // 返り値をCheerioに食わせる
  let $ = Cheerio.load(html);

  // 指定したいテーブルにid:area01を追加
  $('table').eq(3).attr('id', 'area01')

  const hiratsuka_data = $('#area01 tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(5)').text();
```

テーブル番号で指定したいテーブルにidを付与し、それをもとに、
nth-childの番号で取得する・・・という、なんとも強引なやり方になっております。

jQueryの知識が乏しいことでこれ以上のコードが書けないのですが、
もっとスマートに要素を指定する方法はありませんでしょうか？？

もしわかる方いましたら、ご教示いただけますと助かります。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: [teratail:GAS(jQuery使用)のスクレイピングで、class,idの振られていない複数のtableタグから、要素を取得したいです](https://teratail.com/questions/366569) で解決済みの様です。

Answer (score 1):

指定されたURLの表を見ますと、マージされた列があることと、それぞれの行で列数が異なることから、HTMLデータをパースすること自体がすこし複雑そうに思いました。そこで、Cheerioを使用しない方法でHTMLデータをパースしつつ、データを取得する方法について提案させていただきたいと思います。この場合、Sheets APIを使ってHTML tableをパースします。Sheets APIのHTML tableパースは非常に強力と思いますので、これを提案させていただきました。

スクリプトのフローは次の通りです。

1. HTMLデータの取得
2. HTMLデータからそれぞれのTableを取得
3. テンポラルファイルとしてスプレッドシートを作成
4. Sheets APIを使ってHTML tableをパースしてスプレッドシートの各セルへ挿入
5. スプレッドシートからデータを取得し、JSONオブジェクトへ変換
6. テンポラルファイルの削除
7. 結果の表示

このフローをスクリプトに反映させると、次のようになります。

#### サンプルスクリプト

このスクリプトは、HTML tableをパースするためにSheets APIを使用しますので、Advanced Google servicesでSheets APIを有効にしてください。 [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = "https://www.pref.kanagawa.jp/docs/ga4/covid19/occurrence.html";

  // 1. HTMLデータの取得
  const html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  // 2. HTMLデータからそれぞれのTableを取得
  const tables = [...html.matchAll(/<table[\s\S\w]+?<\/table>/g)];

  // 3. テンポラルファイルとしてスプレッドシートを作成
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("temp");
  const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();

  // 4. Sheets APIを使ってHTML tableをパースしてスプレッドシートの各セルへ挿入
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({
    requests: [
      { pasteData: { data: tables[3][0], html: true, coordinate: { sheetId: sheetId } } },
      { deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId: sheetId, startIndex: 0, endIndex: 4, dimension: "ROWS" } } },
      { deleteDimension: { range: { sheetId: sheetId, startIndex: 0, endIndex: 1, dimension: "COLUMNS" } } }
    ]
  }, spreadsheetId);

  // 5. スプレッドシートからデータを取得し、JSONオブジェクトへ変換
  const values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const res = values[0].map((_, c) => values.map(r => r[c])).reduce((o, r) => {
    while (r.length > 0) {
      const [a, b] = r.splice(0, 2)
      if (a) o[a] = b || 0;
    }
    return o;
  }, {});

  // 6. テンポラルファイルの削除
  DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheetId).setTrashed(true);

  // 7. 結果の表示
  console.log(res)
}
```

#### 結果

このスクリプトを実行すると、Logへ次のような結果を確認できます。

```
{
   "横浜市":903,
   "藤沢市":540,
   "厚木市":4003,
   "綾瀬市":1517,
   "大井町":202,
   "湯河原町":206,
   "川崎市":41,
   "小田原市":2177,
   "大和市":4381,
   "葉山町":360,
   "松田町":80,
   "愛川町":778,
   "相模原市":418,
   "茅ヶ崎市":81,
   "伊勢原市":1082,
   "寒川町":65,
   "山北町":57,
   "清川村":10,
   "横須賀市":74,
   "逗子市":686,
   "海老名市":1983,
   "大磯町":288,
   "開成町":220,
   "その他":177,
   "平塚市":3126,
   "三浦市":424,
   "座間市":1983,
   "二宮町":216,
   "箱根町":79,
   "鎌倉市":2051,
   "秦野市":1588,
   "南足柄市":475,
   "中井町":137,
   "真鶴町":47
}
```

この場合、横浜市の値を見たい場合は、`console.log(res["横浜市"])`により`903`を得ることができます。

#### 参考

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [PasteDataRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#pastedatarequest)

Comment: ご教示頂き、ありがとうございます！
私にとっては新しい技術で、まだコードを理解できていないため、
一度、自分なりに知識を増やしてから、またコメントさせていただければと思っております。 とても参考になるご提案、ありがとうとざいます！